# Evaluation of Logical AND in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, logical-and

I have dataframe Cities in pandas. I need to add a boolean column in it that is true if
  1. The city is named after a saint.
  2. The city has an area greater than 50 square miles.

I wrote below conditions for evaluating it.

cities['cond1'] = cities['City name'].str.contains('San') & cities['Area square miles'] > 50
cities['cond2'] = cities['Area square miles'] > 50  & cities['City name'].str.contains('San')
cities
for which i get below result:

```
City    name        Population    Area square miles  cond1        cond2  
 0   San Francisco  852469        46.87              False        True
 1   San Jose       1015785       176.53             False        True
 2   Sacramento     485199        97.92              False        True
```

Both cond1 and cond2 columns check for same condition but give opposite results, which also seems incorrect as I am trying to do AND operation.
Please help me in understanding this result and how can i correctly check for the above conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `>` is lower precedence than `&`, `A > X & B` is parsed as `A > (X & B)` but what you want is `(A > X) & B`.